# EntityFramework Core 3.1 + with MySql or Pomelo rename table to use DBFirst

Tags: mysql, entity-framework-core, ef-core-3.1, pomelo-entityframeworkcore-mysql, db-first

I have done two test projects, one with MySQL.EntityFramworkCore and another with Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore and in both of them the same thing happened to me when obtaining the model from the database.

```
1.- Scaffold-DbContext 'server = x.x.x.x.x; user = xxxx; password = xxxx; database = name;' MySql.EntityFrameworkCore -OutputDir Models -f
2.- Scaffold-DbContext 'server = x.x.x.x.x; user = xxxx; password = xxxx; database = name;' Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql -OutputDir Models -f
```

I have tables like the following in my database:
brand_cars
and when performing the dbFirst process.
It changes my name to BrandCars.

In SQLServer exist the parameter -UseDatabaseNames, but in mysql I have not found it

In the connector options I have not found this option.
https://mysqlconnector.net/connection-options/

Is there a possibility to force that you do not change the name of the database table when performing dbFirst?

The versions of my connectors are as follows:

-For the Pomelo project

Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools 3.1.12

Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql 3.2.4

Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql.Design 1.1.2

-For the MySQL project

Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design 5.0.3

Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools 5.0.3

MySql.EntityFrameworkCore 5.0.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Works fine for me using [Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql](https://github.com/PomeloFoundation/Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql) in its `5.0.0-alpha.2` (or [nightly build](https://github.com/PomeloFoundation/Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql#nightly-builds)) release.

I tested it using the following SQL:

```sql
drop database if exists `So66530902`;
create database `So66530902`;
use `So66530902`;

CREATE TABLE `ice_creams` (
    `IceCreamId` int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `Name` longtext CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 NULL,
    CONSTRAINT `PK_IceCreams` PRIMARY KEY (`IceCreamId`)
);
```

I then executed the following command, using the `--use-database-names` parameter:

```
dotnet ef dbcontext scaffold "server=127.0.0.1;uid=root;pwd=;port=3308;database=So66530902" Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql -c Context -o Models --use-database-names
```

The result is the following class:

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

#nullable disable

namespace IssueConsoleTemplate.Models
{
    public partial class ice_cream
    {
        public int IceCreamId { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
}
```

It should be mentioned that if you don't want EF Core to change the database table names in *any* way, you should also add the `--no-pluralize` flag in addition to `--use-database-names`.

Comment: Thanks for help! I have tested it and it works correctly

Comment: THANKS FOR: if you don't want EF Core to change the database table names in any way, you should also add the --no-pluralize flag in addition to --use-database-names.